# how to turn on the shower shut off valve in the shower wall

Tags: plumbing

My spout was leaking and the plumber shut off the hot water valve in the wall because we needed to find a spout replacement. We replaced the spout and cartridges in the wall and now my husband can't seem to open the hot water valve. It has a place to turn your screw driver. What can he try?

Comment: Show us, please. Valves aren't normally in the wall, and they don't normally require screwdrivers.

Comment: I wonder if he closed the flow restrictors on the valve itself? But a photo would be helpful.